# How to decrease the bar width on a categorical x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, axis, xticks

I want to plot one value on a bar plot but the bar is very thick, I want the bar to be thinner.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data for the bar plot
x = ['Category']
y = [10]

# Create a figure and axis with a narrower width
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

# Adjust the width of the bars
bar_width = 0.3  # Decrease this value to make the bars thinner

# Plot the bars
ax.bar(x, y, width=bar_width)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by using [`xlim()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html). As you have categorical x-axis, it is set at 0. So, you can use limit of -1 and 1 to make it thinner. The more the difference, thinner the bar...

```py
x = ['Category'] 
y = [10]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
bar_width = 0.3
ax.bar(x, y, width=bar_width)
ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another way to change the perspective of the bar width, relative to the x-axis, is to increase the x-axis margins with [`ax.margins(x=1)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html)

---

Given `x = ['Category']`, `ax.get_xticklabels()` results in `[Text(0, 0, 'Category')]`.

Given `x = [0]`, `ax.get_xticklabels()` results in

```py
[Text(-0.2, 0, '−0.20'),
 Text(-0.15000000000000002, 0, '−0.15'),
 Text(-0.1, 0, '−0.10'),
 Text(-0.04999999999999999, 0, '−0.05'),
 Text(0.0, 0, '0.00'),
 Text(0.04999999999999999, 0, '0.05'),
 Text(0.10000000000000003, 0, '0.10'),
 Text(0.15000000000000002, 0, '0.15'),
 Text(0.2, 0, '0.20')]
```

Which does a better job of showing the width of the bar in relation to the range of the x-axis ticks. The bar is the same width, but the range of the x-axis is larger.

[image]